# Why is global variable readable, but not writeable inside a function?

Tags: script, powershell

The following powershell script will output *A, B, A*

```
$x = "A"

function scopetest()
{
    Write-Host $x;
    $x = 'B'
    Write-Host $x
}

scopetest

Write-Host $x
```

Now the strange part:

The first *A* value is from the global scope - it can be read inside the function so obviously the variable is present. However if I write to the variable as-is, the *B* value is not preserved outside the function.

I would expect one of these two outcomes: *[null], B, A* or *A, B, B* (the latter is achieved if I write using *$global:x = 'B'*).

Why is the global variable $x readable inside the function, but not writeable?

Comment: [How Scopes Affect PowerShell Scripts](http://www.howtogeek.com/203778/how-scopes-affect-powershell-scripts/) explains it all ...

Comment: "commands executed within one scope will not affect things in another scope unless specifically told to do so. For example, if $MyVar exists in the Global scope and a script runs a command to set $MyVar to a different value, the Global version of $MyVar will remain unaltered while a copy of $MyVar is placed in the Script scope with the new value. "

Comment: You have a global `$x` and a local `$x`

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of $global and $local - the question is why you can read when you can't write. Anyways it seems to be covered. Thanks :-)

Comment: @DavidPostill, I thought the same at first, but per technet, globally scopped items are members of the local scope, so there should be no opertunity to double allocate without name collision. instead this is just Powershells odd scope handling rules.

Comment: @mhbuur, because that is the way the langague was defined. There are numerous approaches compiled and scripted langagues bind names to memory allocations, and they all have differant rules. Powershell, because it is a managed runtime, is able to apply rules of scope they find desirable. In this case, the daisychaining of scripts or inclusion of a prewritten function into a new script is signifigantly less dangerous if you restrict mutation to the owning scope.

Comment: @FrankThomas If you can add that info to the answer I'll go with it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx

> An item that you created within a scope can be changed only in the 
>             scope in which it was created, unless you explicitly specify a 
>             different scope.

so you could use `$Global:x = ...` to set it.

Powershell scripts are often copied and pasted in blocks to implement functionality, and often methods are written to be used by multiple scripts. By restricting assignment to the defining scope for a variable, you ensure that even if two pasted blocks of code use the same variable name, they cannot improperly change data that the other block depends on, without explicitly stating that they wish to do so. This helps to make blocks more modular, and helps to identify unintentional name collisions.

Edit:

a note on powershell scope:
Powershell cascades scopes, so the local scope always contains objects defined in ancestor scopes (parent, grantparent, global, etc). That means that a variable defined globally or in a parent stack frame (a function calling a function) are always accessible, whereas objects defined in child scopes are not. In this case, the only restriction is that a child scope cannot modify a parent scopes value, unless that scope is defined explicitly.

From: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx

> The following are the basic rules of scope:
>
> ```
>     - An item you include in a scope is visible in the scope in which it 
>       was created and in any child scope, unless you explicitly make it 
>       private. You can place variables, aliases, functions, or Windows
>       PowerShell drives in one or more scopes. 
>
>     - An item that you created within a scope can be changed only in the 
>       scope in which it was created, unless you explicitly specify a 
>       different scope.
>
>
> If you create an item in a scope, and the item shares its name with an
> item in a different scope, the original item might be hidden under the
> new item. But, it is not overridden or changed.
> ```

Comment: Right, so this only applies to changing the value and not reading the value.

Comment: that is correct.